# Template factory function with additional args: friendship issue

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

I'm working on a piece of code that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    // makeA should become a friend
    A() {}
};

template<typename T, typename U>
A<T> makeA(const U & u) {
    (void) u;
    return A<T>();
}

int main() {
    makeA<double>(3);
    return 0;
}
```

But I cannot let `makeA` become a friend of `A`. Is this possible? What is the right syntax?

Comment: first you shouldn't make A() -->constructor private

Comment: What *"right syntax"* are you asking? that makes `makeA` a friend? What exactly is your question? You want to make it friend? Or without making it friend, you want to access the private constructor?

Comment: @Nawaz the answer you posted was what I was looking for. In the friendship declaration I was using `makeA(U)` instead of `makeA(const U &)`. Thanks!

Comment: @Nawaz can I access the private constructor without making it friend???

Comment: @DarioP: Okay, I undeleted by answer if that is what you're looking for. And no, `makeA` cannot access the private constructor if it isn't a friend (if that was possible and good enough, then the language wouldn't have `friend` feature).

Comment: @Shan Uhm what please? That's probably the reason why one want's to have a `friend` function for construction?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it `friend` as:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{

   template<typename TT, typename U>
   friend A<TT> makeA(const U & u) ;

};
```

You could even define the `friend` function inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

While the solution

```
template <typename T>
class A
{

   template<typename TT, typename U>
   friend A<TT> makeA(const U & u) ;

};
```

works, it suffers from the side effect that `makeA<int, int>` is a friend of not only `A<int>` but also a friend of `A<double>`, `A<char>`, etc. In other workds, `makeA<TT, U>` is a friend of every `A<T>`. The friendship granted by `A<T>` is too broad.

You can limit that by using a different design.

```
template <typename T> class AMaker;

template <typename T>
class A
{
   A() {}

   friend class AMaker<T>;
};

template<typename T> class AMaker
{
   public:
      template <typename U>
         static A<T> make(const U & u)
         {
            (void) u;
            return A<T>();
         }
};

int main()
{
   A<double> x = AMaker<double>::make(3);
   return 0;
}
```

Here, friendship granted by `A<T>` is limited to only `AMaker<T>`. `AMaker<int>` is friend of `A<int>` but not of `A<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your program
template

```
class A {
    // makeA should become a friend

    A() {} 
    public:
    template<typename S,typename U>
    friend A<S> makeA(const U & u); //this is correct way to makeA friend of A
};

template<typename T, typename U>
A<T> makeA(const U & u) {
    (void) u;
    return A<T>();
}

int main() {
  makeA<double>(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Now it will work as you can see here
http://ideone.com/1F1l3o

Comment: @Shan My downvote comment was written at the question.

Comment: `friend` functions don't need `public`.

Comment: _will not create any harm right?_ Bloat, unreadable code (if such doesn't harm OK then). And it's nice that _you_ know, but how should other researchers read this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not use `friend`:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    A() {}
public:
    template<class U> static A make(U && u) {
        return A();
    }
};

template<class T, class U>
A<T> makeA(U && u) {
    return A<T>::template make<U>(std::forward<U>(u));
}
```